# Is there a way to search in Extbase and the TYPO3 query builder for words which have a "&shy" inside?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have the problem that the backend users can set a word with a `"&shy;`" character, for example something like "Test&shy ;labor".
If someone uses the frontend search with the word "Testlabor" no match will be found.
In the extbase repository I used this:

`$query->like('name', '%' . $searchWord . '%')`

I can change that to something like this:

```
$query->statement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE hidden = 0 AND REPLACE(name,'&shy;', '') LIKE '%$searchWord%'")
```

Then the word will be found but I have to check all the things the framework normally does, like check if it's hidden and deleted and more complicated, if the result is in the right site tree. Now I just get everything that matches the searchword.

Is there a better way to search for words which have `"&shy;`" inside? Can I use something like that within the TYPO3 query builder?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with QueryBuilder interface

```php
    public function findShy($searchWord)
    {

        /** @var ConnectionPool $pool */
        $pool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
        $connection = $pool->getConnectionForTable('table');

        $queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();

        $query = $queryBuilder
            ->select('*')
            ->from('table')
            ->where("REPLACE(name,'&shy;', '') like :name")
            ->setParameter('name', "%{$searchWord}%");

        // for debug only
        echo($query->getSQL());
        print_r($query->getParameters());

        return $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    }
```

and call it somewhere i.e. in your controller:

```php
DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
    $this->yourRepository->findShy('Testlabor'), 
    'findShy() sample'
);
```

it will create a query with named parameter like (according to your TCA of course):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE (REPLACE(name, '&shy;'­, '') like :name)
  AND ((`table`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`table`.`hidden` = 0) AND
       (`table`.`starttime` <= 1596363840) AND
       ((`table`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`table`.`endtime` > 1596363840)))
```

**Note** that returns associative array with the record **not** a mapped object of your model.

### Optional

If you need mapped model objects anyway, you can mix these two solutions, i.e. first select only the `pids` of your records with `QueryBuilder` and then fetch them with `Query` which implements `QueryInterface` like this:

```php
public function findShy2($searchWord)
{

    /** @var ConnectionPool $pool */
    $pool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
    $connection = $pool->getConnectionForTable('table');

    $queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();

    $preQuery = $queryBuilder
        ->select('uid')
        ->from('table')
        ->where("REPLACE(name,'&shy;', '') like :name")
        ->setParameter('name', "%{$searchWord}%");

    // for debug only
        echo($query->getSQL());
        print_r($query->getParameters());

    $uids = [];
    foreach ($preQuery->execute()->fetchAll() as $item) {
        $uids[] = $item['uid'];
    }

    if(count($uids) > 0){
        $interfaceQuery = $this->createQuery();
        $interfaceQuery->matching(
            $interfaceQuery->in('uid', $uids)
        );

        return $interfaceQuery->execute();
    }

    return [];
}
```